# How to figure out what exactly is clicked in listview?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I have a listview where I create an event listview_itemClick event. I have a `LinearLayout` as listview item. `LinearLayout` has 2 controls. ImageView and TextView.

```
_list = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list);
_recipeAdapter = new RecipeAdapter(this.Activity, _recipes.ToArray());
_list.Adapter = _recipeAdapter;
_list.ItemClick += List_ItemClick;

_list.Scroll += List_Scroll;

private void List_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) {
    // I am looking here a way to figure out if clicked element is ImageView or TextView
}
```

In listitem_click event I am looking for the control which is actually clicked.

Comment: use recyclerview instead of listview  or make custom adapter for listview

Comment: @ApoorvSingh thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Nope, This thins is still pending, I am thinking to use Recyclerview tonight since some guys recommended it to me. if you can make it work using listview it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

`AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs` has a property called `Position` which you can use to figure out which model bound to the `ListView` was clicked.

```cs
private void List_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var postition = e.Position;
    var clickedItem = _recipes.ToArray()[position];
    // do stuff with clicked item
}
```

Comment: thanks for help, the single list item is a linearlayout which have 2 item , textview and imageview, how I supposed to get that from this event.

Comment: That is not the purpose of this event. Why do you need the layout for the row?

Comment: I need to put the image full size and text bottom to image, for getting this I create linearlayout. please suggest me if you have a better approach.

Comment: Since `_receipes` is what you provide the Adapter, I can't see why elements in that array aren't enough for what you want to do.

Comment: do you have any reference to link or article where I can get the detail for how to figure out current object (recipe) on click event. I have done this in Winforms but not sure how to implement here.

Comment: It should be the `clickedItem` I've shown in the code snippet above

Answer (score 0):

When you create a view inside adapter, add a Touch event handler on your controls:

```
control.Touch += (handler)
```

When you press on the element inside the list view item, it would trigger the Touch handler of the view, which is touched.

Comment: when I do this, my listview_itemclick stopped working, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var item = args.SelectedItem as Item;
    if (item == null)
        return;

    await DisplayAlert(item.Text, item.Description, "OK");

    // Manually deselect item
    ItemsListView.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

The `item.Text` and `item.Description` are the listview's selected `Text` and `Description`.

You can use this to work out if the selected item has an `ImageView` or `TextView`.

Comment: Can you integrate my code with it, just settings a global variable like I does in OP would be helpful.

Comment: I have itemclick on my list and I test this code, it doesn't work, tested with itemclick and without itemclick.